# Set interval play audio only loop audio once?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, html5-audio, addeventlistener

I have a set interval and within the set interval I have a sound that needs to be played once and once only but the trouble is the sound keeps looping and doesn't stop does anyone have any idea to what I'm doing wrong here is what I have tried: 
html:

```
<audio id="swoosh">
  <source src="/resources/music/swoosh.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

js:

```
    var swoosh = document.getElementById("swoosh");

    setInterval(function () {
        if ($('.c:contains("01")').length > 0) {
            $(".links #abt").attr("href", "about.html");

            swoosh.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                swoosh.pause();
                swoosh.currentTime = 0;
                swoosh.loop = false;
            }, false);
            swoosh.play();

            //
            if ($('.c:contains("02")').length > 0) {
                $(".links #work").attr("href", "work.html");

                swoosh.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                    swoosh.pause();
                    swoosh.currentTime = 0;
                    swoosh.loop = false;
                }, false);
                swoosh.play();
            }
        }
    }, 10);
```

The aim is to play the sound when the contents of `class="c"` changes so if the contents is 01 the audio should play once and then pause or stop then when it changes to 02 it should play again and then stop or pause etc etc
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it to play only once, why would you put your code inside an interal callback? Intervals by definition do things multiple times.

Comment: Use setTimeout not setInterval

Comment: @Utkanos because I need the contents of .c to be checked over and over again to check when it changes to 02,03,04 etc

Comment: @Sam setTimeout works fine for the first slide but changing to slide 02,03,04 etc the sound doesn't play, I've updated my question to give more of an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Use `setInterval` to get the value of `.c`, and store it as a variable. If the next loop gets a different value to the stored variable, play the sound.

Comment: @sideroxylon I've tried `var countSnd = document.getElementsByClassName(".c").innerHTML;` in the `setInterval` and then outside of it `if (countSnd == 01) {
 swoosh.play();
 swoosh.loop = false;
}` the audio doesn't play

Comment: You need to make it a global variable, declared outside the function - but even then, you will need to compare after each loop to see if the value has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're trying to do that. Store in a variable, the "last sound" reproduced and only plays a new one when it has changed. The listener over "ended" event is unnecessary because you only play once per change.

```
var swoosh = document.getElementById("swoosh");
var lastPlay = "00";

setInterval(function () {
    var cValue = $('.c').text();
    if (lastPlay != "01" && cValue.indexOf("01") >= 0) {
        $(".links #abt").attr("href", "about.html");
        swoosh.play();
        lastPlay = "01";
    }
    else if (lastPlay != "02" && cValue.indexOf("02") >= 0) {
        $(".links #work").attr("href", "work.html");
        swoosh.play();
        lastPlay = "02";
    }
}, 10);
```

Other better way was to add a listener to the change event of the ".c" element, it avoids the "query" every 10ms. But I don't have enough code to show you.